# TiFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 293 (0x125) encountered

Tags: unix, pdf, tiff

I have several tiff image files which I need to convert to pdf files.
Some of the files get converted successfully and I'm able to get the expected output while some of the files are having the above error while I try to convert them and I get the output file as a complete black image.
I'm trying to do the above task using Imagemagick.

I tried to find more about this problem on the internet. What I understood is that the problem is with the T6Options tag of the tiff file, which is (none) in my case. I'm not able to convert this file to any compression, I tried tiffcp, exiftool, tifftopdf but nothing works

Below is the information regarding the file, which I got using exiftool:

ExifTool Version Number         : 11.01

File Name                       : 1000006_1_1007.tif

Directory                       : .

File Size                       : 105 kB

File Modification Date/Time     : 2019:07:16 14:43:09+00:00

File Access Date/Time           : 2019:07:16 14:43:20+00:00

File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2019:07:16 14:43:09+00:00

File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--

File Type                       : TIFF

File Type Extension             : tif

MIME Type                       : image/tiff

Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)

Image Width                     : 1700

Image Height                    : 2200

Bits Per Sample                 : 1

Compression                     : T4/Group 3 Fax

Photometric Interpretation      : WhiteIsZero

Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)

Samples Per Pixel               : 1

Rows Per Strip                  : 32

X Resolution                    : 200

Y Resolution                    : 200

Planar Configuration            : Chunky

Resolution Unit                 : inches

Subfile Type                    : Single page of multi-page image

Fill Order                      : Normal

Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 449 bytes, use -b option to 
extract)

Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 249 bytes, use -b option to extract)

T4 Options                      : Fill bits added

T6 Options                      : (none)

Page Number                     : 1 0

Image Size                      : 1700x2200

Megapixels                      : 3.7

Comment: What was the error? Unknown tags are warnings and would not cause the file not to be generated? You can avoid warnings by adding -quiet after convert and before the input in your command line.  Please show your command. Post your tif file to some free hosting service and put the URL here. That way we can test it. Please note that Imagemagick is a raster processor and will not vectorize output PDF files. It will only imbed the raster image into a vector PDF shell.

Comment: There is no error. Just this warning. File got generated as a complete black image. Adding -quiet doesn't help. I can't share the tif image, it's client's sensitive data.

Comment: What software created the tool? Non-Adobe software can create special tags and may not code them properly. So it could be corrupt. Without a file, it will be very hard to know what or why?

Comment: I can view the tiff image properly using any photo viewer. But Imagemagick can't convert it to pdf. Can it be corrupt if that is the case?

Comment: Can it convert it to GIF or PNG? What is your exact command line and what version of Imagemagick, date of the version and platform? What version of libtif?

Comment: Same Black image when I convert to gif or png. I'm using centos-release-7-6.1810* and ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2019-02-01 Q16, LIBTIFF v4.0.3

Comment: Try upgrading libtiff to the most current. I have 4.0.10

Comment: I was able to convert these files using "tifffile" python library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to convert these files using "tifffile" python library

Comment: Strange. Tifffile does not support any fax compression scheme.

Comment: Don't know much about it. But it worked for me